# How to calculate P(A<B|B<1)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Say A = price change tomorrow
and B = price change the day after tomorrow
Daily price changes are independent and normally distributed.
Let's assume the price today is 100 cents, and that the price falls at least a cent tomorrow.

If for example I want to calculate the probability that the price falls to 0 the day after tomorrow, but also requiring that the price falls at least a cent tomorrow), do I calculate P(A<-100-B |B<1)? If so, how do I calculate this probability with the variable B being involved in the A probability?

Comment: If price changes are independent, the distribution of B cannot impact the distribution of A. Maybe you can provide more context?

Comment: Yes, the price movements are independent each day, but the context of the question requires that the price change next day is at least a dollar, but we cannot know the actual price change tomorrow. This is why the variable B is included in the probability of A, because we need the price to fall to 0 (which is an 100change from today, rather than tomorrow)